# Remove and Disable Win 10 PIN for Work/School Account

Tags: windows-10, windows-hello

I have found lots of ways to remove the PIN logging from the Windows 10 Windows Hello service but they all apply to a non work/school login account. My account is a work account and when I want to remove the PIN the remove button is greyed out. How can I re-enable that button so I can remove then pin then disable Windows Hello on this machine?

Comment: Have you contacted your IT Administrator.  I do believe there is a group policy which by enforces you to have a pin for your account.

Comment: @Ramhound I am the IT admin, it is a stand alone laptop that I use with my own business MS account. I found the GP which enables/disables the pin completely but not that lets me remove it first, and when disabled I am still asked for my pin